# Django all-auth login redirect URL

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm using **django-allauth** to create google login.

At present I'm using the following in my `settings.py`

`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = /relative/path/`

Even though my website is working on `https`, but the google login redirects it to `http`.

What am I missing here?
It works fine when I write the complete path in `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`.

Ok, a friend of mine has suggested me [`ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL`](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html).
But again this won't redirect to the method from which login process started. It is like hardcoding the method.

Comment: isn't the redirection configured in the google app ?

Comment: We give all the redirect urls there, but where to redirect is decided at the time of login.

Comment: Are you hosting using nginx ? Also can you paste your LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL ?

Comment: I can use nginx's redirect, but I don't want to change the protocol on which the user started the login process.

Comment: So the issue I think is that your site works both in http and https. And when the user is in http, user will be taken to http itself after login. If that is the case, I recommend to make your site work only in https. Never make it work on http. From nginx redirect to https all the time.